# Parse json in java for a particular format

Tags: java, json, rest, restful-architecture

I'm new to java. Could you please help me in parsing the below json in java.
I have a json which contains a list of empid's and for each empid there will be couple of dept id's.

Please see the below format

```
empid  deptid
1       111
1       222
1       333
2       123
2       111
```

So I will have the data in json as above format.
And I need parse this json in java and I need to store this data into a map.

Like `Map<String,List<String>>` where key will be the empid and the value will be dept id's.

So please help me with this.

Note : I will get input as Json Object from client. I need to parse this json object in java.

Json Representation :

```
  {"employees":[
   {"empid":"1","deptid":["111","222","333"]},
   {"empid":"2","deptid":["123","111"]},
]}
```

Thanks.

Comment: That format isn't JSON. Could you post what the actual JSON will look like?

Comment: I don't have the real Json representation , that's the reason I given in the table format

Comment: Json will look something like this.
{
     [
           "empid" : "1",
           "deptid" : ["111","222","333"]
     ],
     [
       "empid" : "2",
        "deptid" : ["123","111"]
     ]
}

Comment: @Naresh - "Something like" .... That isn't valid JSON.  Step 1 - read the JSON syntax graphs on http://json.org.  Step 2 - look at all of the JSON libraries for Java, as listed on the same site.

Comment: This is the actual json representation :

 {"employees":[
   {"empid":"1","deptid":["111","222","333"]},
   {"empid":"2","deptid":["123","111"]},
]}

Answer (score 1):

Use gson library  https://github.com/google/gson

use typetoken to parse json string to java object

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
Type type = new TypeToken<Map<String,List<String>>>(){}.getType();
Map<String,List<String>> obj = gson.fromJson(jsonData, type );
```

Comment: Sorry to ask this . I'm a beginner just learning the things. Instead of using Gson, can't we use simple core java to store the data in map from json.

Comment: I am not aware of any core java library for JSON to Java and vice-versa. I mainly use GSON and JACKSON library to do this.